# soy nuevo, al momento de ejecutarlo funciona pero cuando voy a terminar el proceso me sale el error, estoy creando una interfaz de usuario

Tags: java

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
> at java.base/java.util.Vector.removeElementAt(Vector.java:580)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.removeRow(DefaultTableModel.java:469)
> at controlador.Controlador.limpiarTabla(Controlador.java:45)
> at controlador.Controlador.add(Controlador.java:76)
> at controlador.Controlador.actionPerformed(Controlador.java:136)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

```
public class Controlador implements ActionListener {

EstudianteDAO dao = new EstudianteDAO();
Estudiante estudiante = new Estudiante();
Vista vista = new Vista();
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();

 public Controlador(Vista v) {
    this.vista = v;
    this.vista.btnListar.addActionListener(this);
    this.vista.btnAgregar.addActionListener(this);
    this.vista.btnEditar.addActionListener(this);
    this.vista.btnDelete.addActionListener(this);
    this.vista.btnActualizar.addActionListener(this);
    this.vista.btnNuevo.addActionListener(this);
}

void nuevo() {
    vista.txtId.setText("");
    vista.txtNombre.setText("");
    vista.txtTelefono.setText("");
    vista.txtCorreo.setText("");
    vista.txtNombre.requestFocus();
}

void limpiarTabla() {
    for (int i = 0; i < vista.tabla.getRowCount(); i++) {
        modelo.removeRow(i);
        i = i - 1;
    }
}

public void delete() {
    int fila = vista.tabla.getSelectedRow();
    if (fila == -1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(vista, "Selecione una Fila");
    } else {
        int id = Integer.parseInt((String) vista.tabla.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());
        dao.Delete(id);
        System.out.println("El Reusltaod es" + id);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(vista, "Usuario Eliminado");
    }
    limpiarTabla();
}

public void add() {
    String nom = vista.txtNombre.getText();
    String correo = vista.txtCorreo.getText();
    String tel = vista.txtTelefono.getText();
    estudiante.setNombre(nom);
    estudiante.setCorreo(correo);
    estudiante.setTelefono(tel);
    int r = dao.agregar(estudiante);
    if (r == 1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(vista, "Estudiante Agregado con Exito");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(vista, "Error");
    }
    limpiarTabla();
}

public void Actualizar() {
    if (vista.txtId.getText().equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(vista, "Se sugiere que el usuario seleccione "
                + "la opción \"Editar\" para solucionar el problema.");
    } else {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(vista.txtId.getText());
        String nom = vista.txtNombre.getText();
        String correo = vista.txtCorreo.getText();
        String tel = vista.txtTelefono.getText();
        estudiante.setId(id);
        estudiante.setNombre(nom);
        estudiante.setCorreo(correo);
        estudiante.setTelefono(tel);
        int r = dao.Actualizar(estudiante);
        if (r == 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(vista, "Usuario Actualizado con Exito.");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(vista, "Error");
        }
    }
    limpiarTabla();
}

void centrarCeldas(JTable tabla) {
    DefaultTableCellRenderer tcr = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    tcr.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    for (int i = 0; i < vista.tabla.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(tcr);
    }
}

public void listar(JTable tabla) {
    centrarCeldas(tabla);
    modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tabla.getModel();
    tabla.setModel(modelo);
    List<Estudiante> lista = dao.listar();
    Object[] objeto = new Object[4];        
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
        objeto[0] = lista.get(i).getId();
        objeto[1] = lista.get(i).getNombre();
        objeto[2] = lista.get(i).getCorreo();
        objeto[3] = lista.get(i).getTelefono();
        modelo.addRow(objeto);
    }
    tabla.setRowHeight(35);
    tabla.setRowMargin(10);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == vista.btnListar) {
        limpiarTabla();
        listar(vista.tabla);
        nuevo();
    }
    if (e.getSource() == vista.btnAgregar) {
        add();
        listar(vista.tabla);
        nuevo();
    }
    if (e.getSource() == vista.btnEditar) {
        int fila = vista.tabla.getSelectedRow();
        if (fila == -1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(vista, "Seleccione Una fila");
        } else {
            int id = Integer.parseInt((String) vista.tabla.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());
            String nom = (String) vista.tabla.getValueAt(fila, 1);
            String correo = (String) vista.tabla.getValueAt(fila, 2);
            String tel = (String) vista.tabla.getValueAt(fila, 3);
            vista.txtId.setText("" + id);
            vista.txtNombre.setText(nom);
            vista.txtCorreo.setText(correo);
            vista.txtTelefono.setText(tel);
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == vista.btnActualizar) {
        Actualizar();
        listar(vista.tabla);
        nuevo();

    }
    if (e.getSource() == vista.btnDelete) {
        delete();
        listar(vista.tabla);
        nuevo();
    }
    if (e.getSource() == vista.btnNuevo) {
        nuevo();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Si tienes `i` incrementándose en el `for` ¿Para qué lo decrementas con `i = i - 1;`?